# How to have a customized context menu per tab in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, which allows you to close all tabs on a certain domain or a second-level domain. I use the current tab as basis for that decision and let the user select what they want to close from a context menu. Now, to avoid confusing labels like "close all from domain" and "close all from SLD", I would like to show the likes of "close all from google.com" and "close all from images.google.com".

The question is how make the context menu items bound to the current tab and update them when the user switches a tab or even just opens the context menu? Should be easy, but I really struggle to find a solution.

Comment: Simply send a message from content script on mousedown with the location.hostname to the background page script which will update the context menu accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that, but that's very concrete. There are different ways of triggering context menus, I can think of a hotkey, for instance. Surely I should not be trying to cover all of them, that would be madness. That way it will be very hard for me to make sure that it works for all users.

Comment: I think there are only two ways: mousedown (99.99999% usage) and keyboard (0.000001% usage), which you can detect by checking the Apps key or Shift-F10 on Windows and some other keys on other platforms. This is easily doable. Anyway, there are no other solutions.

Comment: Use the actual event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu

Comment: Sounds like that along with content script should probably be the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, IIRC `contextmenu` fires too late so the message to the background won't make it in time before the menu is shown. Anyway, this topic has at least several answers that explain the same thing I did.